# Matlab survival curve log rank test

Tags: matlab, survival-analysis, significance, ecdf

I am trying to do survival analysis in matlab and want to calculate log rank test scores among several curves. I found a possible code to do log rank [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22317-logrank/content/logrank.m). But based on its description, it can only do log rank test between two groups. What if I have 3 or more curves?

Comment: can't you perform pair-wise tests?

Comment: I can perform pair-wise tests, then I get multiple p values from log rank test. How can I combine all those into one? Take average?

Comment: Full disclosure: I am not an expert on the subject. This might be a more appropriate question over at the "cross validated" SO site http://stats.stackexchange.com/. Once you have a programming question or problem you can come back and ask it here...